# Reformat code like phpStorm in VIM

Tags: vim, plugins, phpstorm, vim-plugin

I once used phpStorm (before I switched to Vim). I really liked the way phpStorm could reformat your code. (phpStorm would format right before you commit your change). Does Vim have a reformat plugin like phpStorm?

Comment: For those of us who have never used that IDE, could you provide a before/after example of what it does?

Comment: Do you really need to use Vim for PHP? I can't see any use cases where it offers an advantage over PHPStorm if you're writing PHP code. If you just like the way it does things, PHPStorm has Vim keybindings, so you can use all the same shortcuts. Also, you have syntax highlighting, code inspections, error highlighting etc that Vim can't do. All in all, I find it's very hard to get the same amount and quality of PHP code done in the same time using Vim.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can reformat the code if you got a syntax plugin for it: (normal mode) `gg=G`